# Object Types Only Return as "LIGHT"...?

Tags: python, add-on

It's just another one of those moments in coding where my brain is so deep in the code that there must be something obvious that I'm missing or just never even learned (I'm fairly new to coding in Blender).

I am trying to write a code that sorts all existing objects in the scene into lists based on each object's type. The issue seems to be that, no matter what I do, every object is added to only one of the lists because they're all returned as having a "LIGHT" type. Obviously, that is not true, as the scene consists of three separate types of objects (image shown below).

[image]

It seems like it should be such a simple and straightforward script but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

My Code:

```
import bpy

camera_list = []
light_list = []
object_list = []

for object in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    
    if bpy.context.object.type == "CAMERA":
        camera_list.append(object)
    if bpy.context.object.type == "LIGHT":
        light_list.append(object)
    else:
        object_list.append(object)
```

Comment: by the way, since your are new here: if an answer helps you, commenting is nice but better is checking the checkmark left to the answer. So other users know that the answer helps and the one who answers will get some reputation.

Comment: Hey fyi in python there are some keywords and built-in types you should try to not redefine like `object` (that's why it's highlighted in orange in the script) but rather do : `for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:` for instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your are comparing with bpy.context.object instead of object. So it does not take the loop object into account.

so the correct code is:

```
import bpy

camera_list = []
light_list = []
object_list = []

for object in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    
    if object.type == "CAMERA":
        camera_list.append(object)
    if object.type == "LIGHT":
        light_list.append(object)
    else:
        object_list.append(object)
        
print("obj", object_list)
print("cam", camera_list)
print("light", light_list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel like I always have more questions than answers so I'm glad there are people like you to help me find my way.

Comment: glad i could help. We all started with nearly no knowledge sometime ;)